# Can I use Ethereum's Whisper protocol to transfer files?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, whisper

Here is an code example:

```
shh.post({
  "from": myIdentity,
  "topic": [ web3.fromAscii(appName) ],
  "payload": [ web3.fromAscii(myName), web3.fromAscii("What is your name?") ],
  "ttl": 100,
  "priority": 1000
});
```

What stops us from putting files in the payload i.e., large base64 encoded or hexadecimal string?

Comment: Well I had similar question like you for cpp-ethereum but the answer I got there for sure will help you, [you can find it here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9356/is-possible-to-transfer-data-between-nodes-using-cpp-ethereums-whisper-protocol/9406#9406)

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/9356/87

Answer (score 1):

Currently for the proof of concept nothing prevents this. However the next version of the protocol will include:

- Hard limit on the payload size
- Proof of work proportional to `Size_bytes*Time_to_live`

[Source](https://gist.github.com/gluk256/4654922ca45eb9d0846d941d7ca326f4)