# Is possible to transfer data between nodes using cpp-ethereum's whisper protocol?

Tags: cpp-ethereum, whisper, swarm, hosting

Right now I am working on developing a standalone application in C++ using libraries of cpp-ethereum, I was looking at the source code for cpp-ethereum and an idea stuck into my mind that wouldn't it be cool if we can use whisper protocol of cpp-ethereum for transferring actual data like actual file transfer? Can we do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Of course it's possible what you suggesting, but no, because you have a major mixup in terminology.

- For a peer 2 peer communication layer, have a look at **devp2p**. Here is the [specification](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/%C3%90%CE%9EVp2p-Wire-Protocol).
- For actual data/file transfer have a look at **swarm**, the peer 2 peer [file hosting protocol](https://github.com/ethersphere/swarm). (See [also](http://swarm-gateways.net/bzz:/swarm/).)
- **Whisper** is a peer 2 peer encrypted messanging protocol, currently pushed by [status.im](https://status.im/), the latest spec is [here](https://gist.github.com/gluk256/4654922ca45eb9d0846d941d7ca326f4). As far as I know is only geth featuring a pretty current implementation, no idea about the C++ status.

In general, just a heads up, the C++ client is deprecated for production use. If you are interested in further developing against swarm or whisper, take a look into [go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum). Or contribute to cpp-ethereum.

Comment: Well surely above answer made my vision clear about what I have to do but let us say I have to send only a little bit amount of data some Kbits or may be less than that and I want it to be transfer different than blockchain data. So from your point of view in this situation where does the whisper protocol stands?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to give you details about whisper other than the linked resources above. Not sure what the limits are.